# Showing Toast Notification just below the Widget Layout in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, toast

I am working on Android Widget which have few buttons, i want to show the Toast just below the Widget layout in the launcher screen as some click those buttons.

Answer (score 1):

You can position your toast using `toast.setGravity()` method.

Example: `Toast.makeText().setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.LEFT, 0, 0).show();`

Go [HERE](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html#Positioning) for the full explanation.

Comment: iI will show the toast in the Top left corner of the launcher but i want to show it just below the widget,

Comment: It was just an example. Go and read the documentation. You'll have to find out how to get the position of the widget. Then how to position the Toast according to the Widget.